# Автоматический расчёт дня недели в структуре tm

Tags: c, структуры

Чтобы хранить время использую структуру struct tm time. В программе заполняю поля структуры подобным образом

```
        do
        {
            puts("Enter the year");
            scanf("%d", &inf.time.tm_year);
        } while (!(inf.time.tm_year>1970 && inf.time.tm_year<2100));
        inf.time.tm_year=inf.time.tm_year - 1900;
        do
        {
            puts("Enter the month");
            scanf("%d", &inf.time.tm_mon);
        } while (!(inf.time.tm_mon>=0 && inf.time.tm_mon<=11));
```

Возможно ли автоматически заполнить поле дня недели ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция **mktime** исправляет неправильные числа секунд, минут, и т.д. затем вычисляет день недели, день в году с 1 января.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <time.h>
int main(){
struct tm t;
t.tm_year = 2018 - 1900 ;
t.tm_mon = 4 ; // май - 1
t.tm_mday = 20 ;
t.tm_hour = 12 ;
t.tm_min = 30 ;
t.tm_sec = 30 ;
std::cout<<"t.tm_wday="<<t.tm_wday<<" t.tm_yday="<<t.tm_yday<<std::endl;
mktime(&t);
std::cout<<"t.tm_wday="<<t.tm_wday<<" t.tm_yday"<<t.tm_yday<<std::endl;
t.tm_mday = 32 ;
mktime(&t);
std::cout<<"t.tm_mon="<<t.tm_mon<<" t.tm_mday="<<t.tm_mday<<
  " t.tm_wday="<<t.tm_wday<<" t.tm_yday="<<t.tm_yday<<std::endl;
}
```

Сегодня воскресенье, **wday** должен стать нулём.

```
> g++ mktime.cpp 
> ./a.out 
t.tm_wday=4196973 t.tm_yday=0
t.tm_wday=0 t.tm_yday=139
t.tm_mon=5 t.tm_mday=1 t.tm_wday=5 t.tm_yday=151
```

Comment: учитывая, что вопрос по Си, лучше обойтись без `<iostream>`...

Comment: @AlexGlebe   , а что будет, если не учитывать, что в этой структуре всё начинается с нуля , и записывать в них данные , начиная с единицы ?

Comment: Будет то, что вы говорите на разных языках. Вы просите день недели в мае, вам дадут в июне. Про год даже страшно представить, что будет в 3918 году.